# I want to mapping MultipartFile with userId

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to upload excel file then save it to Product DB, I have User, Product Tables but product mapped by user Table. so I got error when I try to upload.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "USER_ID"; SQL statement:
```

Since I need to check who upload the file. mapping is nessesary. I don't know where should I put the code to map the userId.

```
@PostMapping("/api/excel/upload/")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        String message = "";
        if (ExcelHelper.hasExcelFormat(file)){
            try{
                excelService.save(file);
                message = "upload suceed: " + file.getOriginalFilename();
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        message = "please upload file";
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
```

```
@Service
public class ExcelService {
    @Autowired
    ProductRepository repository;

    public void save(MultipartFile file){
        try{
            List<Product> excelEntities = ExcelHelper.excelToExcelEntity(file.getInputStream());
            repository.saveAll(excelEntities);
        }catch (IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException("failed" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Editted post ##

```
@EntityScan
@Entity
@ApiModel
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
```

I added the ExcelEntity!

```
public static List<Product> excelToExcelEntity(InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(SHEET);
            Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.iterator();

            List<Product> entities = new ArrayList<Product>();

            int rowNumber = 0;
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                Row currentRow = rows.next();

                // skip header
                if (rowNumber == 0) {
                    rowNumber++;
                    continue;
                }
                Iterator<Cell> cellsInRow = currentRow.iterator();

                Product excelEntity = new Product();

                DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
                int cellIdx = 0;
                while (cellsInRow.hasNext()) {
                    Cell currentCell = cellsInRow.next();
```

Comment: Please include the definition for your `Product` entity class.  And also, include the actual SQL statement from the error message (currently, it has been cut off or not included).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edit post!

Comment: Check your `excelEntities` collection, which apparently does not have values set for the user ID.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I update the post, actually I'm very new to write the code. Could you help me to how should I set values for userId?

Comment: Everything looks weird to me. You're using `@RequestParam` to post a data that is being sent via the body? And there is no loading of user id anywhere in your code, etc.

Comment: Yes. I'm using form-data in postman. key:file , value: file.xlsx but I don't know how to set user variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the below code in your controller to get UserDetails of the logged in user.

```
User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Comment: I got same error..
caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "User_ID"; SQL statement:

Comment: Did you tried mapping "user" object in your "product" object and still getting this error. Can you send me how your code looks like after mapping of user object in project object.

Comment: @Panchan Goyal  Those are mapped. I'm getting keep same error. how can I send code to you?

Comment: SOLVED. I set the contextHolder in service. it was so simple problem.