# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-security

I'm using springboot, Jpa, H2 database. I'm trying to upload excel file to DB but I got error

```
NULL not allowed for column "user_Id"; SQL statement:
```

I have product and user tables, product are mapped by User tables. I'm thinking it should be work since I'm using Jwt and if they are logged user. excel upload then save Product fields. excel file contains such as productName, description, etc.

```
User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

```
@Entity
@ApiModel
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long id;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private User user;
```

```
@PostMapping("/api/excel/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(); // this part
        String message = "";
        if (ExcelHelper.hasExcelFormat(file)){
            try{
                excelService.save(file);
                message = "success: " + file.getOriginalFilename();
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        message = "please upload file";
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
```

this is my previous question but I couldn't solve the problem yet. please help! it getting same error.
[I want to mapping MultipartFile with userId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251944/i-want-to-mapping-multipartfile-with-userid)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.
I set the contextHolder in service. it was so simple problem.

Comment: Can you give more of an explanation so others can learn from what you solved please?

Comment: I get the contextHolder with header in service then set with other table.  was so simple problem